# facebook. publish updates to users

Tags: facebook

Is the a way to programatically publish updates to users that have liked an external page on fb? I know fb used to provide the ability to administer a page once it reached some threshold of likes but i believe that has been deprecated. Is someone aware of some other way to do this still?